# If statement ends program inside for loop

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.3.2 and I'm writing a program that takes a number, and adds it to a list in ascending order. The program works, but I added a statement that checks to see if the number that the user inputs is already in the list, and when its true, the loop ends and the program stops. Can someone give me any suggestions as to why this is, and how to prevent it?

```
L = float(input('Input a number: ')) #Gets input from user
list1 = [L] #Places the first input in a list

for L in list1: #Begins loop
    L = input('Input a number: ') #More input

    if L == ('stop'): #User tells program to stop
         print(list1)
         break #Ends program

    elif L != ('stop'): #The user does not stop the program
        L = float(L)

        if L not in list1: #New input not in list
            N = len(list1)#Length of list
            M = max(list1)#Max value of list
            m = min(list1)#Min value of list

            if L < m: #Checks if input is smaller than the min of list1
                list1.insert(0, L)#Inserts new input at start of list

            elif L > M:#Chacks if new input is larger than the max of list1
                list1.append(L)#Add new input at ent of list1

            elif L < M and L > m:#New input is between max and min of list1

                for x in range(0 , len(list1)):#x is the number of indexes in list1

                    if L < list1[x]:#Checks the size of each index to the input
                       list1.insert(x, L)#Inserts input between upper and lower values
                       break

        elif L in list1: #Checks if new input is already in list
            print ('Already in list!')

    else: #Program fails
        print('I\'m afraid I can\'t do that Dave.')#LOL
        break
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean when this is true? -> "elif L in list1: #Checks if new input is already in list"

Comment: Yes, the loop ends when that statement is true.

Comment: The problem is in how you're looping. You shouldn't modify the counter. Use some variable other than L

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: When you do "for L in list1" - L is the iterator. But then you modify it by using it to store user input. Use a different variable to store user input.